# How to stop ScrollView (on TextView) from scrolling to the top while pinch-zooming

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, scrollview, scale

I want to implement pinch-zooming on my scrolling TextView.

The code below always scrolls to the top while I am zooming.

I want to keep its scrollY intact. Please tell me how to do it.

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.scroll_layout.*

class ScrollTextActivity : Activity() {
    private var scaleFactor = 1.0f
    private val defaultTextSize = 30.0f
    private val scaleListener = ScaleListener()
    private val scaleGestureDetector: ScaleGestureDetector by lazy {
        ScaleGestureDetector(this, scaleListener)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.scroll_layout)
        text_view.textSize = defaultTextSize * scaleFactor
        scroll_view.setOnTouchListener { _, e ->
            if (e.pointerCount > 1) {
                scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)
                true
            } else
                super.onTouchEvent(e)
        }
    }

    private inner class ScaleListener : ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener() {
        var oldFocusY = 0f
        var oldScrollY = 0
        var oldSize = defaultTextSize

        override fun onScaleBegin(detector: ScaleGestureDetector): Boolean {
            oldFocusY = detector.focusY
            oldScrollY = scroll_view.scrollY
            oldSize = text_view.textSize
            return true
        }

        override fun onScale(detector: ScaleGestureDetector): Boolean {
            scaleFactor = (scaleFactor * detector.scaleFactor)
                    .coerceAtMost(10.0f)
                    .coerceAtLeast(0.1f)
            text_view.textSize = defaultTextSize * scaleFactor
            scroll_view.scrollTo(0, (
                    (oldScrollY + oldFocusY) * text_view.textSize / oldSize
                            - oldFocusY).toInt()
            )
            return true
        }

        override fun onScaleEnd(detector: ScaleGestureDetector) {
        }
    }
}
```

and scroll_text.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="start|top"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                android:text=" Long \n long \n long \n long \n long \n long \n long \n text..."/>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Moreover, it sometimes scrolls back to the intended position when you

1. Put your finger on the screen and move it. The text scrolls. Keep it on.
2. Put your thumb on the screen and move it. The text zooms. (And the top of text is seen.)
3. Lift up only your thumb.

But it does not always happen. More strangely, sometimes it starts to work as expected.

Target APIs are minSdkVersion 19, targetSdkVersion 29.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this must be a bug in TextView or something on some devices e.g. Amazon Fire HD 10 (api 22).

Other devices of mine look working.

I removed the ScrollViews and set the detector/listener directly to TextView, and it still had the same problem.

I replaced the ScaleGestureDetector / Listener with some handcrafted code (see below), and it still had the same problem.

I will give up and ignore such buggy devices.

reference:

```
//var scaleFactor = 1f
//scroll_view.setOnTouchListener(ZoomTouchListener())

inner class ZoomTouchListener : View.OnTouchListener {
    private val firstFocalPoint = PointF()
    private var firstSpan = 0f
    private var firstScaleFactor = 1f
    private var firstScrollY = 0
    private var firstScrollX = 0
    private var isInProgress = false

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    override fun onTouch(v: View, e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        if (e.pointerCount > 1) {
            when (e.actionMasked) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN,
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    startZooming(v, e)
                }
                MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP,
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,
                MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL -> {
                    isInProgress = false
                }
                else -> {
                    if (!isInProgress) {
                        startZooming(v, e)
                    } else {
                        val focalPoint = getFocalPoint(e)
                        scaleFactor = (firstScaleFactor * getSpan(e, focalPoint) / firstSpan)
                                .coerceAtMost(10.0f)
                                .coerceAtLeast(0.1f)
                        text_view.textSize = defaultTextSize * scaleFactor
                        v.scrollY =
                                ((firstScrollY + firstFocalPoint.y) * scaleFactor / firstScaleFactor
                                        - focalPoint.y).coerceAtLeast(0f).toInt()
                        horizontal_scroll_view.scrollX =
                                ((firstScrollX + firstFocalPoint.x) * scaleFactor / firstScaleFactor
                                        - focalPoint.x).coerceAtLeast(0f).toInt()

                    }
                }
            }
            return true
        } else
            return false
    }

    private fun startZooming(v: View, e: MotionEvent) {
        firstFocalPoint.set(getFocalPoint(e))
        firstSpan = getSpan(e, firstFocalPoint)
        firstScaleFactor = scaleFactor
        firstScrollX = v.scrollX
        firstScrollY = v.scrollY
        isInProgress = true
    }

    private fun getFocalPoint(e: MotionEvent): PointF {
        var sumX = 0f
        var sumY = 0f
        for (i in 0 until e.pointerCount) {
            sumX += e.getX(i)
            sumY += e.getY(i)
        }
        val focusX = sumX / e.pointerCount
        val focusY = sumY / e.pointerCount
        return PointF(focusX, focusY)
    }

    private fun getSpan(e: MotionEvent, focalPoint: PointF): Float {
        var devSumX = 0f
        var devSumY = 0f
        for (i in 0 until e.pointerCount) {
            devSumX += abs(e.getX(i) - focalPoint.x)
            devSumY += abs(e.getY(i) - focalPoint.y)
        }
        val devX = devSumX / e.pointerCount
        val devY = devSumY / e.pointerCount
        val spanX = devX * 2
        val spanY = devY * 2
        return hypot(spanX, spanY)
    }
}
```